# Array push object inside an array when a key with some particular name exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, arraylist

I have an array of objects like below

```
[
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-07"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-08"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-09"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-10"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-11"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-07"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-08"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-09"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-10"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Turbohaler",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-11"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Septron",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-07"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Septron",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-08"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Septron",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-09"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Septron",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-10"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "medication": {
        "name": "Septron",
        "time": [
            "2018-09-11"
        ]
    }
}
]
```

lodash or underscore provided great functions to minimalise the code, but still those libraries didn't help me solve the above problem

I want to achieve something like below

```
[
  {
    "medication": {
    "name": "Turbohaler",
    "time": [
    "2018-09-07",
    "2018-09-08",
    "2018-09-09",
    "2018-09-10",
    "2018-09-11"
  ]
 }
},
{
 "medication": {
 "name": "Septron",
 "time": [
    "2018-09-07",
    "2018-09-08",
    "2018-09-09",
    "2018-09-10",
    "2018-09-11"
  ]
}
```

} 
 ]

The above result is formed by grouping an array  of objects with same key name (Medication) in our case, and fetching all its values together and merging it into a single object in an array. I have tried different approaches and it failed, If someone could try a bit for above expected output, it will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `O(n)` solution for the problem you are facing. In addition, use **spread syntax** on array so that if the `time` array has multiple items it is handled properly.

```js
var arr = [{
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-07"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-08"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-09"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-10"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-11"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-07"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-08"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-09"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-10"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Turbohaler",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-11"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Septron",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-07"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Septron",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-08"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Septron",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-09"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Septron",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-10"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "medication": {
      "name": "Septron",
      "time": [
        "2018-09-11"
      ]
    }
  }
];
var tempObj = {};
arr.forEach((item)=>{
  if(!tempObj[item.medication.name]){
    tempObj[item.medication.name] = item;
  } else {
    tempObj[item.medication.name].medication.time.push(...item.medication.time);
  }
});
var res = Object.values(tempObj);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: sounds like a perfect solution, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and then collect all values for a given name and render then a new array.

```js
var data = [{ medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-07"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-08"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-09"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-10"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-11"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-07"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-08"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-09"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-10"] } }, { medication: { name: "Turbohaler", time: ["2018-09-11"] } }, { medication: { name: "Septron", time: ["2018-09-07"] } }, { medication: { name: "Septron", time: ["2018-09-08"] } }, { medication: { name: "Septron", time: ["2018-09-09"] } }, { medication: { name: "Septron", time: ["2018-09-10"] } }, { medication: { name: "Septron", time: ["2018-09-11"] } }],
    grouped = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { medication: { name, time } }) => m.set(name, (m.get(name) || []).concat(time)), new Map),
        ([name, time]) => ({ medication: { name, time } })
    );
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: looks like a simplified approach. Thanks @Nina